# How Change URL in GWT application?

Tags: java, url, gwt

I wish if anyone can help me in this issue,

How I can change the address bar content when I change the page in GWT? (e.g: on Aboutus www.mysite.com/aboutus)

Also if user type in the address bar (www.mysite.com/aboutus) the GWT application forward it to Aboutus page?

Thanks

Comment: Window.setLocation("") doesn't work out for you?

Comment: how I can do this in request and navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [activities and places.](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces) It's a way to structure your web app. The application will be organized in places, views, and activities, The view contains just code that builds the interface, and the activity contains what the View actually does. Each place/activity/view corresponds to a URL. For some apps this is a simple and convenient way to organize things.

Answer (score 0):

the address bar is set according to your web page so if you have, say : `welcome.html` you must place this script into it :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="module/welcome.nocache.js"></script>
```

the src attr is referring to the entry class in the module (by module here I mean : `module.gwt.xml` file)

So this script is connecting your html page with the logic written in GWT Java EntryClass

the module representing your '`aboutus`' on  `www.mysite.com/aboutus` so if you hava a page related to this module you will find it on:

`www.mysite.com/aboutus/this_is_html_related_to_aboutus_module.html`

SO it's all one to one :One Page to One Module

or Many to One         :Multi div tags in one Page and More Logic `(if-else)` to specify any piece of code will match suitble div one

Answer (score 0):

You should use your widget to navigate like this:

```
Anchor nameLink = new Anchor();
nameLink.setText(rec.get("userSeq") + " / " + rec.get("userName"));
nameLink.getElement().setAttribute("style", "padding: 5px;");
String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + GWT.getModuleName() + ".html";
if (GWT.getHostPageBaseURL().contains("localhost") || GWT.getHostPageBaseURL().contains("127.0.0.1")) {
    url = url + "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997";
}
nameLink.getElement().setAttribute("style", "padding: 10px;");
nameLink.getElement().setAttribute("href", url + "#customer");
```

And your controller or presenter class should implement `ValueChangeHandler<String>`, e.g.

```
public final void onValueChange(final ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
String token = event.getValue();

if (token != null) {
    String[] tokens = History.getToken().split(":");
    final String token1 = tokens[0];
    final String token2 = tokens.length > 1 ? tokens[1] : "";

    if (token1.equals("customer")) {

        GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
            public void onFailure(final Throwable caught) {
            }

            public void onSuccess() {
                CustomerAuctionView view = CustomerAuctionView.getInstance(service);
                CustomerAuctionPresenter presenter = CustomerAuctionPresenter.getInstance(service, eventBus, view);
                presenter.run();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with

```
newPageButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
        History.newItem("customer");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Through `JSNI`, you can find the `URL`.

```
public static native String getURL() 
  /*-{

var x = "URL: " + location.href;
alert(x);


  }-*/;
```

Comment: Does this address the question "How I can change the address bar content when I change the page in GWT"? Please be careful that you answer addresses the question. I've formatted your code a bit so that others can see what you suggest. You need to indent source code with 4 spaces, otherwise Stackoverflow doesn't recognize it as source code.